# Polymer's vulcanize comments php script

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am using Polymer. In my index file i have some php script that gets commented after I vulcanize it.
Is it possible to prevent vulcanize from commenting my php script?

### I have tried:

- searching in vulcanize's githup repository for relevant options.
- searching in the same place for related

with no avail...

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your polymer components in a separate directory, and serve them as static content. Vulcanize only those files and serve the vulcanized version as a static file.

import the static polymer files from the html your php scripts creates.